# XmlHttpRequest cannot load API_URL. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest

I am using a HTTPRestService method to get some data through api call.Here is my code for that :

```
function getDataFromAPI(inputData) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post(API_URL_HERE, inputData).success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);

    }).error(function (data) {
        deferred.reject();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

This is the code i have written inside the web.config file in the API project:

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-
    With,Content-Type,Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" 
    value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
  </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
 <handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" 
  type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
  preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers></system.webServer>
```

This is the code i have written inside the Global.asax.cs file :

```
internal protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //// Get objects.
        //HttpContext context = base.Context;
        //HttpResponse response = context.Response;
        //// Complete.
        //base.CompleteRequest();

        if (Context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Context.Request.Headers["Origin"]);
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        }
    }
```

Still i am getting this 401 unauthorized error in chrome and edge browser.
What should i need to do in order to fix this ?

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET, maybe you have to add RequestVerificationToken to the request?

Comment: Are you really getting a 410 response or did you mistype 401?

Comment: Sorry mistyped 401